# appending nested list elements recurisvely to new list

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested

the below code snippet flattens the nested list and the elements to the new list recursively but couldn't append all the elements to the list.

> expected output : [1,2,4,5,6,7,5,8]
>
> my output : [1,2,8]

```
def foo(l): 
   result = []
   for i in l:
     if type(i)==list:
       foo(i)
     else:
       result.append(i)
return result


input_list = [1,2,[4,5,[6,7],5],8]

print (foo(input_list))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are resetting `result` in each call. Pass it inside the function.

```
def foo(l,result): 
  for i in l:
   if isinstance(i,list):
     foo(i,result)
   else:
     result.append(i)
  return result


input_list = [1,2,[4,5,[6,7],5],8]
result=[]
print (foo(input_list,result))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Upvoted; I would also suggest using `isinstance` to check for the type

Comment: @Bahrom: Yeah makes sense. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks thats worked ....:)